# Kerbal Construction Time

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

I installed Kerbal Space Program V1.22 and downloaded the Mod Kerbal Construction Time for more realism.
But for some reason this mod doesn't show up during the game and construction and research time is down to 0 as in vanilla game.

The KCT version file has a lot of version info:

```
{
"NAME":"Kerbal Construction Time",
"URL":"http://magico13.net/KCT/.version",
"DOWNLOAD":"http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/92377-0-24-2-Kerbal-Construction-Time-Release-v1-0-2-%289-3-14%29",
"CHANGE_LOG_URL":"http://magico13.net/KCT/KCT_changelog",
"VERSION":"1.2.2.0",
"KSP_VERSION":{
    "MAJOR":1,
    "MINOR":0,
    "PATCH":4
 },
 "KSP_VERSION":{
     "MAJOR":1,
     "MINOR":0,
     "PATCH":4
 },
 "KSP_VERSION_MIN":{
     "MAJOR":1,
     "MINOR":0,
     "PATCH":4
 },
 "KSP_VERSION_MAX":{
     "MAJOR":1,
     "MINOR":0,
     "PATCH":4
 }
```

}

Is this KCT Version compatible with KSP 1.2.2?

If not, is there a compatible version available?

If it is compatible, what might be a reason why it doesn't run on my pc?

My other mods are

- Chatterer
- Kerbal Engineer
- Mechjeb2
- Docking Port Alignment Indicator
- ScanSAT
- Stage Recovery
- Kerbal Alarm Clock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you downloaded KCT 1.2.2 which is for KSP version 1.0.4

I don't think there is a stable build of KCT that support KSP 1.2.2 but there are dev builds:

[Last stable KCT release (for KSP 1.1.3) on KSP forums](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/83342-113-kerbal-construction-time-134-june-25-2016-unrapid-planned-assembly/)

[Dev builds thread on KSP forums](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/62900-kerbal-construction-timestagerecovery-dev-thread/)

Comment: I will take a look at the Dev Build when I am Back Home, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. I definitly had the wrong version. I'm ashamed...

Comment: No need to be ashamed - it's really hard keeping track with the KSP mods sometimes - so many sources out there.